# Calculate $\int_0^\pi{x\sin{x} \over 1+\cos^2x}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I am trying to get started on

$$\int_0^\pi{x\sin{x} \over 1+\cos^2x}dx$$
The usual trick I am familiar with would be to substitute $y=\tan{x \over 2}$. This doesn't seem to work in this case.

Comment: Doing quick numeric check says $\pi^2/4$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the trick that $\int_a^bf(x)=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)$ we get
$$\int_0^\pi\frac{x\sin x}{1+\cos^2x}=\int_0^\pi\frac{(\pi-x)\sin(\pi-x)}{1+\cos^2(\pi-x)}=\int_0^{\pi}\frac{(\pi-x)\sin x}{1+\cos^2 x}$$
From this $$2\int_0^\pi\frac{x\sin x}{1+\cos^2 x}=\int_0^{\pi}\frac{(\pi-x)\sin x}{1+\cos^2 x}+\int_0^\pi\frac{x\sin x}{1+\cos^2 x}=\pi\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin x}{1+\cos^2 x}$$
With the substitution $u=\cos x$ we get
$$\pi\int_{-1}^1\frac{1}{1+u^2}=\pi(\arctan(1)-\arctan(-1))=\frac{\pi^2}{2}$$
So $$2\int_0^\pi\frac{x\sin x}{1+\cos^2 x}=\frac{\pi^2}{2}\\\int_0^\pi\frac{x\sin x}{1+\cos^2 x}=\frac{\pi^2}{4}$$

Answer (score 5):

$$I=\int_0^\pi{x\sin{x} \over 1+\cos^2x}dx$$

Let $u= \pi-x$
$$I=\int_0^\pi{(\pi-x)\sin{x} \over 1+\cos^2x}dx$$

Thus

$$2I=\pi\int_0^\pi{\sin{x} \over 1+\cos^2x}dx$$

$$2I=-\pi\int_0^\pi{1 \over 1+\cos^2x}d(\cos x)$$
$$2I= - \pi \arctan(\cos x) \bigg|_0^{\pi}$$
$$=-\pi (\arctan(-1) - \arctan(1))$$

Thus

$$I=\frac{\pi^2}{4}$$

Comment: Check your result numerically.  This is far from the correct solution.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm gonna have to disagree with this solution: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral_0%5E%CF%80+(x+sin(x))%2F(1+%2B+cos%5E2(x))+dx

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt thanks, checking

Comment: You left off the $\pi$. Also $arctan(cos(\pi)) = arctan(-1) = -\pi/4$. Then $2I = -\pi(-\pi/4-\pi/4) = \pi^2/2$ so $I = \pi^2/4$.

Comment: @martycohen thank you so much! I was checking the earlier steps..